# Right way to specify the download subdir in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I can `download` the file to the default subdir which is the `download` by.

```
await page.goto('https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1');
```

However when I specified the download subdir with the following code, then it did not download:

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './tmp/order'});
```

The error is:

```
Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?_export_=page%3A1
<     at navigate (C:\code\js\wbot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:103:37)
<     at <anonymous>
<     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

My puppeteer is `1.9.0`. What I am missing here?